# If I am using Bar End Shifters, is there a compelling reason to change the old brake levers?

Tags: road-bike, brakes, build, brake-levers

I have old dull aluminum break pulls on dropbars with suicide levers.  The new brakes are Tektro long reach.  Should I change the levers?  If so what is a good quality/price lever to buy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't have to… That said, Tektro makes some very nice and inexpensive levers – both drop bar levers ([RL340](http://www.tektro.com/_english/01_products/01_prodetail.php?pid=67&sortname=Lever&sort=1&fid=3)) and interrupter levers ([RL720](http://www.tektro.com/_english/01_products/01_prodetail.php?pid=58&sortname=Cyclocross&sort=2&fid=3)) which are **much** more effective than suicide levers. At the very least, I would take off the suicide levers, I've never had good luck with them. The problem that I had with suicide levers was that they had so much flex in them that it was hard to get good braking unless your wheels were *perfectly* true and the brakes were adjusted *very* close to the rim.

Found an extensive discussion on suicide levers [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5267/why-dont-brakes-come-with-safety-levers-any-more).

Comment: Get rid of the suicide levers, they are just ineffective and dangerous.

Comment: The RL520 are for linear pull/v-brakes.  They won't work properly with road calipers or cantilevers.  There are other similarly prices levers that work with road calipers.

Comment: Thank you! Good catch, the right levers are the RL340, added links above.

Comment: I checked out some notes on why suicide bars suck..  and I strongly dislike these old levers anyway.  so I picked up those 340's .. they were available here in Japan for $25 -  thanks!