# What of Papillionaire? Looking for a Remi

Tags: shopping

Is anyone familiar with Papillionaire Bikes? They were (are?) an Australian manufacturer with a presence here in the US up until a year ago. Their website is still up but I've been unable to make contact or ascertain anything about them, and there doesn't seem to be a way to order their bikes anymore. I'm guessing they folded but I can't see anything officially stating so. A shame, they looked promising.

I'm mostly wondering because I'm in the market for a bike and was very interested in their [Remi](https://www.papillionaire.com/au/our-bike/remi) model. Any suggestions for a similar spec'd bike of the same style? I prefer new to get all the latest components but not opposed to used if I can find something suitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bike looks very much like all the other retro inspired steel frame road bikes. The exceptional parts are stem shifters and suicide levers, both of which are best avoided. Search for CrMo frame and you should find many similar options.

Comment: Why these levers are called _suicide levers_: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/5268/30402